# Pass parameters from ASPX page to Windows Service

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I'm really not sure how this can be done. I want to pass some parameters from my aspx page to my windows service. Could you share me your ideas on this because I've been searching over the internet and I can't find any.

Note that I plan that the aspx that I'm making is currently running.

Below is the diagram so that you can visualize.
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are the web application and the windows service installed on the same machine or on different ones?

Comment: These two are in one server.